# Solr relevancy score different on replicated nodes

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Version Solr 7.4.0 zookeeper 3.4.11 
Achitecture Two boxes Machine-1,Machine-2 holding single instances of solr

We are having a collection which was single shard and single replica i.e s=1 and rf=1

Few days back we tried to add replica to it.But the score for same query is coming different from different replicas.

http://Machine-1:8983/solr/MyTestCollection/select?q=%22data%22+OR+(data)&rows=10&fl=score&defType=edismax&qf=search_field+content&wt=json

"response":{"numFound":5836,"start":0,"maxScore":**4.418847**,"docs":[

whereas on another machine(replica)

http://Machine-2:8983/solr/MyTestCollection/select?q=%22data%22+OR+(data)&rows=10&fl=score&defType=edismax&qf=search_field+content&wt=json

"response":{"numFound":5836,"start":0,"maxScore":**4.4952264**,"docs":[

The maxScore is different.

Relevancy gets affected due to sharding but replication was not expected as same documents get copied to other node. score explaination gives issue with docCount and docFreq uneven.

idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:
1.050635000
docCount                :**10020.000000000**
docFreq                 :**3504.0000000**

idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:
1.068795100

docCount                 :**10291.000000000**
docFreq                  :**3534.0000000**

***Update:Tried the same on different collection.Both instances give same score.Seems like a issue with particular collection.***

How can we correct the original collection.

Comment: Initial guess - the number of deleted documents differ on the two replicas (they'll still affect the score until they've been expunged). Their mergefactors might be different, or a document failed being committed to one of the replicas while indexing - and depending on your settings when submitting documents - that might not be propagated as a fatal error. Deleting the replica and adding it again should force replication of the complete index again. Issue a fetch all query to all the replicas and see if the number of documents are different (since the docCount differ)

Comment: http://machine-1:8983/solr/MyTestCollection/select?q=*:*&rows=0                          
http://machine-2:8983/solr/MyTestCollection/select?q=*:*&rows=0                         
http://machine-1:8983/solr/MyTestCollection/select?q=*:*&shards=machine-2:8983/solr/MyTestCollection

All giving same number of documents.
We can delete replicas but which one should be deleted.How we can know which node is giving correct score.

Comment: Collection state below

"shards":{"shard1":{"range":"80000000-7fffffff","state":"active","replicas":{ "core_node2":{"core":"MyTestCollection_shard1_replica_n1","base_url":"http://machine-1.com:8983/solr","node_name":"machine-1:8983_solr","state":"active",
"type":"NRT","force_set_state":"false","leader":"true"},"core_node4":{"core":"MyTestCollection_shard1_replica_n3","base_url":"http://machine-2:8983/solr","node_name":"machine-2:8983_solr","state":"active","type":"NRT",
"force_set_state":"false"}}}},

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing this while indexing is going on, it is possible that the master has more docs than the replica (the replica is behind, always catching up), so the doc numbers might vary slightly. If you get this when no indexing is going on, and you have commited, then it should be a bug.

Comment: We didn't do it during indexing.Also we tried the same on different collection.Both instances give same score.Seems like a issue with particular collection.

Comment: you sure both replicas have commited all docs? if they have different commit settings they might differ